# Text is blurry until animation is finished?

Tags: css

I have an text animation and is blurry, it looks ugly.

```css
.text{
  animation: move 2s ease-in;
  position: relative;
  
  /* Added for demo purpose */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    right: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    right: 0.2em;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0em;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Text</span>
```

I use chrome!

How can I make that blur gone? Thank you!

Comment: Please add proper detail of your issue.

Comment: during the animation the text is blurry..when the animation is finish its show normal font

Comment: It's not blurry... Its transition effect of opacity 0 to 1

Comment: how can i make that look nice?

Comment: Please find below answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: `how can i make that look nice` what do you understand by ' nice ' ?  It goes from opacity 0 to 1 in a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.text{
  animation: move 2s ease-in;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(15%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

</div>
```